# How to wrap this "TakesScreenshot" function into method?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, takesscreenshot

I am using this code to capture screenshot in selenium webdriver with JAVA:

```
  File screenshot = ((TakesScreenshot) driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
    
    
    try {
        FileUtils.copyFile(screenshot, new File("C:\\projectScreenshots\\homePageScreenshot.png"));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
```

But when I wrap this code into function like below, then it throws me `NullpointerException`.

```
public static void TakesScreenshot()
{
            

File screenshot = ((TakesScreenshot) driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
     try {
            FileUtils.copyFile(screenshot, new File("C:\\projectScreenshots\\homePageScreenshot.png"));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
}
```

Comment: How does `TakesScreenshot` (bad name for a method, by the way) know what `driver` is? Where is it declared? You could pass it as a parameter to the method.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca I answered my question using your comment. Please free to edit my comment if it contains errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved `NullpointerException` by using this below function:

```
public static void takeScreenshot(String file, WebDriver driver) {
    try{
        File scrFile=((TakesScreenshot) driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
        FileUtils.copyFile(scrFile, new File("C:\\Users\\"+file+".png"));
    } catch(IOException ioe) {
        ioe.getStackTrace();
    }
}
```

To call the above function, we need to use this line in the script:

```
takeScreenshot("Screenshot", driver);
```